# Bubble Chart using Shiny App - Labels and Bubbles out of sync

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, bubble-chart

First of all here is my data:

```
 df <- structure(list(rowname = c(
      "AA - 2018", "AA - 2019", "AA - 2020",
      "AB - 2018", "AB - 2019", "AB - 2020"
    ), Class = c(
      "AA", "AA",
      "AA", "AB", "AB", "AB"
    ), Year = c(
      2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2018L,
      2019L, 2020L
    ), Vol = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.7), Profit = c(
      -0.1,
      -0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, -0.9
    ), Amount = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), Division = c("Bonds","Bonds","Bonds","Equity","Equity","Equity")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I am trying to create a bubble chart where the size of the bubble is dependent on the amount and is positioned based on the profitability (as a % of the amount) on the x-axis and the volatility (as a % of the amount) on the y-axis. I have added a slider that uses the year column so that the bubbles can change as the slider changes year.

I am developing a shiny application with a drop-down box that allows the use to select a division or All divisions. I have two questions:

1. I want the axis' to change with the drop-down box selection and this works but unfortunately the labels and bubbles go out of sync (and in some cases disappear) when i move the slider. The bubbles and labels do not go out of sync when i comment out the condition at the beginning of the RenderPlotly section.
2. Is there a better way to code the condition section without using if statements?

   ```
    divvar = c("All"="All","Bond"="Bond","Equity"="Equity")

    Bound <- 0.1

    y_high <- max(df$Vol) + Bound
    y_low <- 0

    x_high <-max(df$Profit) + Bound
    x_low <- min(df$Profit) -Bound

    ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Title"), # Application title
    sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(     

      selectInput("Division","Select Division",divvar,selected = "All"),width=2),

    mainPanel(plotlyOutput("plot", width = "100%"))
    )
    )
    )

   server <- function(input, output) {


    output$plot <- renderPlotly({

    #Labels and Bubbles are in sync if below section is commented:

    #----

    fil_table <- df %>% select(Vol,Profit,Division) %>% filter (Division == input$Division) 

    if(input$Division == "All") {}

    else

    {y_high <- max(fil_table$Vol) + Bound
    x_high <- max(fil_table$Profit) + Bound
    x_low <- min(fil_table$Profit) + Bound
    }
                     #----

                     ggplotly(ggplot( if(input$Division == "All") {df}

                     else

                     {df %>% filter (Division == input$Division)},
                     aes(x = Profit, y = Vol, size = Amount, color = Class, frame = Year)) +
               geom_point(alpha = 0.2) + scale_size(range = c(5,40)) +
               geom_text(aes(label = Class), size = 5)+
               geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype="dotted", color = "black", size=0.75)+

               scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent,expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0,y_high)) +


               scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent,expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(x_low,x_high)) +
               labs(title = "Profitability vs Volatility", 
                    x = "Profitability %", 
                    y = "Volatility %")
      })

    }

   shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of the lower bound if `Bounds/Equity` is chosen was wrong, you used `+` instead of `-`. In general, it is ok to use `if/else`, but I wouldn't use it directly in the `ggplot` call, so I simplified it a bit. I advise you to have a look at and *use* a style guide to write better readable code, for example the [tidyverse style guide](https://style.tidyverse.org/).

```
df <- structure(list(rowname = c(
  "AA - 2018", "AA - 2019", "AA - 2020",
  "AB - 2018", "AB - 2019", "AB - 2020"
), Class = c(
  "AA", "AA",
  "AA", "AB", "AB", "AB"
), Year = c(
  2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2018L,
  2019L, 2020L
), Vol = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.7), Profit = c(
  -0.1,
  -0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, -0.9
), Amount = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), Division = c("Bonds","Bonds","Bonds","Equity","Equity","Equity")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

divvar = c("All"="All","Bonds"="Bonds","Equity"="Equity")

Bound <- 0.1

y_high <- max(df$Vol) + Bound
y_low <- 0

x_high <-max(df$Profit) + Bound
x_low <- min(df$Profit) -Bound

library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Title"), # Application title
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(     
      
      selectInput("Division","Select Division",divvar,selected = "All"),width=2),
    
    mainPanel(plotlyOutput("plot", width = "100%"))
  )
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({

    if (input$Division == "All") {
      plot_data <- df
    } else {
      plot_data <- df %>% filter(Division == input$Division)
      y_high <- max(plot_data$Vol) + Bound
      x_high <- max(plot_data$Profit) + Bound
      x_low <- min(plot_data$Profit) - Bound
    }
    
    ggplotly(ggplot(plot_data,
                    aes(x = Profit, y = Vol, size = Amount, color = Class, frame = Year)) +
               geom_point(alpha = 0.2) + scale_size(range = c(5,40)) +
               geom_text(aes(label = Class), size = 5)+
               geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype="dotted", color = "black", size=0.75)+
               
               scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent,expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0,y_high)) +
               
               
               scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent,expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(x_low,x_high)) +
               labs(title = "Profitability vs Volatility", 
                    x = "Profitability %", 
                    y = "Volatility %"))
  })
    
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Thank you, i thought it was something simple!